# Why can I not initialise a VideoView object by the FindViewById method?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-videoview

I want to play a mp4 video which I have put in the folder Resources/raw. The following is my code and the error "A field initialiser can not be applied to the non static fiel or non static method or property" (translated from German) is displayed, 'FindViewById(Resource.Id.vv)' being the underlined part. In my layout file I have included a VideoView with the id 'vd'. I would be very thankful for every help to play my video!

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App_1_design
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        VideoView vid = (VideoView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.vv);
```

Comment: Try this instead 

`VideoView vid = new VideoView`
 `vid = (VideoView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.vv);` 
or have it in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to initialize controls in the `OnCreate` event after setting the layout file like:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    VideoView vid;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        vid = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.vv);

        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.sample_video);
        vid.SetVideoURI(uri);
        vid.Start();
    }
}
```

### Update

> why now the error message says 'resource does not contain a definition
>   for raw'?

[image]

Make sure the build action of your video is AndroidResource. And then we could access this resource through `Resource.Raw.[yourVideoID]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem indeed, you helped me a great deal! Any Idea, why now the error message says 'resource does not contain a definition for raw'? I have included a folder 'raw' (also tried 'Raw') in the project under resources.

Comment: @nelson Please see my update. We could create a raw folder in the resource and put the videos there.

Comment: Now, I changed the build action to AndroidResource. I have used your code and now it underlines 'SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main)' with the error 'java.lang.nullhandlerexception' when I am debugging my program. Even when I delete the code concerning the video the error still stays and i can not debug my program anymore. Then it says 'attempt to invoke interface method void'. I could only fix this by creating a new solution and copying my whole code in the new project.

Comment: @nelson `activity_main` is my layout's name I think you need to change it to yours. You can't delete it directly as Activity needs a root content. This error may be caused by your layout files. Do you put some unexpected controls there? Try to create a new layout to display your video view.

Comment: that is also my layouts name. I am trying this, but I am also a little bit lost at this atm. Currently going in another direction. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @nelson Can you successfully play the video using video view now? If so, please accept my answer here.

Comment: I am finding a way around it... thanks though, your answer should be accepted!